# How to extract the length or time that a value is above a threshold in a 3-axis plot

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, fft

I am generating a frequency spectrogram using Python's `STFT` function.  An output is being generated as shown in the graphic below (x-axis is time, and y-axis is frequency).  The color is determined by the magnitude of the Short-Time Fourier Transform.

**I am trying to figure out how to determine when the yellow area exists for longer than, say, 20 time-steps.**  Ideally, I would like to trigger an event notification if the magnitude is detected to be high over this period of time.

Pseudo-code:
`if (magnitude is yellow for 20 time steps); print (notification)`

The x-axis is time, and the y-axis is frequency, and the magnitude is determining the color.  I am having a difficult time figuring out how to determine when the magnitude lasts longer than 20 time steps.

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\test5.txt")
data.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(data['Z'], fs=250, nperseg = 100)

med_filter = scipy.signal.medfilt(np.abs(Zxx), 15)

ax1.pcolormesh(t, f, med_filter, vmin=0, vmax=0.001)

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, sharex = False)
```

[image]

Comment: What is yellow for you?

Comment: @mrCarnivore Yellow is the magnitude of the Fourier Transform.  So, areas where it is yellow, there is a higher magnitude.  I didn't get a chance to add a colorbar to show the values of the colors.

Comment: I know. But you need to specify exactly which color you define as yellow. A lot of colors between green and yellow could be counted towards yellow or green...

Comment: Okay, I understand.  For the sake of this example, it makes no difference to me because I can adjust it later, if needed.

Comment: Are you looking for me to specify a value for "yellow"?  Is it not painfully obvious when looking at the graph what yellow is?

Comment: It most definitely is not obvious. since there is no such thing as "true" yellow in computer screens. You must specify a threshold or even n area in the color spectrum which you define as yellow. Which values from the colorcoding lead to colors you would define as "yellow"?

Comment: How do I extract the values of the colorcoding?

Comment: Now you start to see the real problem and why nobody can currently help you... You need to find out the colors for the colorcoding or devise a threshold yourself and then you are almost done.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Maybe I didn't understand that when I made the question.  The medfilt outputs a multi-dimensional array, which the colormesh uses to make the plot.  But I'm not sure the best method to extract these values....

Comment: How does one go about specifying a threshold for the color yellow?